# how to get key in angularjs without ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular and looking to get the key value pair without using ng-repeat.
I can get the exact data when I traverse :- activeCard.card.content.causes.cause 
Json looks like this :-

content: Object

causes: Object

cause: "Eating Junk Food"

Comment: Whats your controller code?

Comment: I am parsing the data in controller code That is returning $scope.activeCard

Comment: Why -1 is this not possible? because I tried with ng-repeat and it was throwing syntax errors.